# error with RabbitMQ on iOS

Tags: ios, rabbitmq

In my iOS app I'm using RabbitMQ wrapper from https://github.com/bimawa/AMQProtocol

```
AMQPConnection *connection = [[AMQPConnection alloc] init];
NSError *error,*error1,*error2;
[connection connectToHost:server onPort:port error:&error];
[connection loginAsUser:login withPasswort:password onVHost:@"/" error:&error1];

AMQPChannel *channel = [connection openChannelError:&error2]; // Get error here!
```

On the last line I get the error **"Failed to open a channel"**:

```
2014-06-27 11:17:06.094 MyApp[40055:60b] TCLib>> AMQPException AMQP_RESPONSE_LIBRARY_EXCEPTION: Failed to open a channel: Argument list too long
2014-06-27 11:17:06.107 MyApp[40055:60b] TCLib>> open channel error: Error Domain=AMQPChannel Code=-5 "Failed to open a channel" UserInfo=0x9abe330 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to open a channel}
```

Server, host, login and password are working. I've checked them on android app.

Can't find out why it fails to open a channel. Can you recommend something?

Comment: try just channel = [connection openChannel];

Comment: it has only this method `- (AMQPChannel *)openChannelError:(NSError **)errorOpenChannel;`

Answer (score 0):

may be its too late for answer but may be it's helpful for other.:)

in my situation the problem was from i had error in login to 'vhost' or the

`[connection loginAsUser:login withPasswort:password onVHost:@"/" error:&error1];`

line and i was trying to open the channel of null connection .
the problem was permission check mechanism in rabbit server.

**update**:

for example check the error after each line that you pass it to a method like this:

`if(error!=nil){
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    return;
}`